# Use arrays' position as function parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to pass positions of a list of arrays in a function, but I'm definitely missing something.

This is my script :

```
// function to display the results 
function display(array){                                 
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("x");
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName('x')
  var value = sheet.getRange("G4:I4").setValue(array[x][y]) //sets the range to the value 
}

// function that creates or searches for the array
function recherche() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("x");
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName('x')
  
  var arrays = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,10]
  ]

  display(arrays[0][0]) // first time it is executed it should display arrays[0][0] or 1

  return arrays
}

// function to display the next value 
function next(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("x");
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName('x')
  display(recherche()[x+1][0]) // should display arrays[1][0] or 6
}
```

Am I doing something stupid or did I just miss something?

Thx

Comment: To be honest with you I don't understand a thing you are doing.  There are so many undefined variables, `array[x][y]`, `display(results[0][0])`, `display(recherche[x+1][0])`

Comment: Sorry I corrected my mistake. Stupid copy/paste. it should be display(recherche()[0][0]). I made the edit on the original post.

Comment: Still not right, what is `x`?

Comment: This is the gist of my question I guess. [x] and [y] should be the arrays's position as passed in the recherche() and next() function.

Comment: You might be interested in [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this:

First:

```
function myTest() {
  let i = 0;
  let arrays = rechershe();  // will display arrays[0][0]
  i++;
  next(arrays,i);
}

function next(arrays,i) {
  display(arrays[i][0]);
}
```

Or:

```
function myTest() {
  let i = 0;
  let arrays = rechershe(); // will display arrays[0][0]
  i++;
  next(arrays[i][0]);
}

function next(value) {
  display(value);
}
```

Or:

```
function myTest() {
  let i = 0;
  let arrays = recherche(); // will display arrays[0][0]
  i++;
  function next() {
    display(arrays[i][0]);
  }
  next(); // will display arrays[1][0]
}
```

And still another:

```
function myTest() {
  let i = 0;
  let arrays = recherche();
  i++;
  next = () => display(arrays[0][i]);
  next();
  i++;
  next();
}

8:15:58 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:16:00 AM  Info    1
8:16:00 AM  Info    2
8:16:00 AM  Info    3
8:15:59 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```